# How can I construct a where clause based on a parameter value in Microsoft Transact SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where if I pass a parameter `@param`, then I need my `where` clause to be

```
where field1 = @param
```

But, depending on the value of `@param1`, the `where` clause might be

```
where field1 in (... several possibilities)
```

Also, the `where` clause could be

```
where field1 is in (... several possibilities) 
   or field1 like ...%
```

So, based on what I pass, the `where` clause can have multiple "personalities". How do you do this?

I looked at creating a string

```
@sqlquery = "select whatever from wherever where ..."
```

and then executing it with `sp_executesql`, but I'm still not sure exactly how to do this. This appears to be the direction I need to go in.

Comment: Can you provide a list of the possible values?

Comment: Have you considered a branching logic model using conditional checks that inspect your parameter to choose which branch to execute? If you have rule that out, it could add to your question to describe why.

Comment: I had not considered that.  This may be the best way.  Thank you.

Comment: Can branching logic be done in any way other that if statements?  Can I use a case statement for this?

Comment: `CASE` and `IF` are fundamentally different, with `IF` being a "flow control" statement and `CASE` being a function. The branching model will increase your code maintenance overhead, but it will also enable you to optimize each of the query types to the workloads they are performing

Comment: [`CASE` is an expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression), not a statement or a function. As for the problem at hand, [kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) sure comes to mind.

Comment: Might the issue extend beyond `field1`, i.e. could you need to check more than one column? Can the conjunction vary, e.g. `ShoeSize = 10 and ( ShoeWidth in ( 'W', 'WW' ) or LaceType = 'HookAndLoop' )`? How will you specify `and`, `or`, `kinda`, parentheses and all of the other possibilities? It doesn't get prettier.

Comment: A wrapper procedure that invokes several sub-procedures depending on the requirements will give you the best outcome, since each procedure will have an execution plan more suited to the desired query. You might consider passing a table-type parameter which can be joined to for better and simpler filtering. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it sure is, and somehow that's the term that I just couldn't come up with - thank you!

Comment: @Stu that works well if the query is simple and static and the combinations of parameters is finite, but not very well if it is complex, often-changing, or the number of distinct combinations becomes large. I'd rather manage dynamic SQL and conditional recompile (e.g. needed for date ranges but not point lookups) than a procedure for every single combination of parameters.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes I would agree and have used both methods, with up to about 5 clearly distinct versions I would implement as dedicated procedures otherwise it probably makes more sense to dynamically build and paramterise as best as possible.

Comment: @Stu right because you know as soon as you build 5 some department is going to ask for 3 more

Comment: Users are the worst.

Comment: @Stu It's called a [layer-8 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_8) :-)

Comment: The kitchen sink method may do the trick.  It is possible that multiple crimetypes can be provided and that seems to be the best way to add to the string.  Thanks!.  I will attempt that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method outlined on @aaronbertran's blog (KitchenSink) did indeed resolve my issue. There were even more complicating factors but this translated into all of them.  Thank you for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the field and param, so it will be

```
where  @param like '%field1%'
```